# Trigger script on usb plug - Linux Mint 19

Tags: linux-mint, usb, udev

I want to trigger a script when a USB is plugged in, I'm on Linux Mint 19.

The consensus appears to be to add a rule in `/etc/udev/rules.d/my_rule.rules`.

I tried several lines:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", RUN+="/home/user/foo"
```

or

```
ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="usb-storage", RUN+="/home/user/foo"
```

or

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", RUN+="/home/user/foo"
```

And many others from the answers I found in SE. But none of them work. Of course `/home/user/foo` exists, is flagged as executable and, for the purpose of testing, is just:

```
#!/bin/bash
geany
```

Also I restart everytime udev service:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/udev restart
```

Am I missing something? Could be a hardware issue? Could be related to Mint?

Thanks